# How to print out a string to have multiple lines in the print out

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i'm using python and I have an email dict being pulled from a large .csv column file where some values might have multiple values. I'm implementing this column into a vertex for a graphing database so order is key. I am using Gremlin API.

Here's what I have for my code:

```
contact_email_name_map = defaultdict()

for i in range(len(contact_email)):
    contact_email_name_map[contact_email[i]] = account_name[i]  

for key, value in contact_email_name_map.items():
    print(key, "-------------------", value)
```

what happens now:

```
output:
example@aol.com
apples@aol.com
oranges@aol.com;pears@aol.com
bear@aol.com
```

what I would like to happen:

```
output:
example@aol.com
apples@aol.com

oranges@aol.com 
pears@aol.com

bear@aol.com
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` on the delimiter:

```
for key, value in contact_email_name_map.items():
    for email in key.split(";"):
        print(email, "-------------------", value)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help, since the email data frame is the key in this default dict, not the value

Comment: @JBlock well then just swap key and value in the loop. Will edit to show.